# Storage limitations in Phonegap apps

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am working on a phonegap app and need to store data locally. And I am dealing with a lot of data. 
Which means that localStorage is not the choise for me. WebSQL seems to have higher limitations (50MB iOS, 200MB Android) but I am afraid this could not be enough. 
What alternatives do I have?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html It cant depend on your target platforms. Seems you might want to use the platforms file system via a plugin

Comment: 50MB of plain text? ... what are you storing?

Comment: In the backend we have a file structure with files and directories. To displayy the file structure in the app I do not want to fetch the files again and again so that the user needs to wait for the request. Currently we have over 300 000 entries in our table. In worst case the user could explore all the directories so I would need to store the 300 000 entries locally.

Comment: you can use the cordova sqlite plugin https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage